# MYSQL create table error with multiple foreign keys

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to create a table with multiple foreign keys, and am getting an error.  I am unsure what I'm doing wrong, and I've been tinkering with it for a while.  I'm sure its something small and stupid, but help is appreciated.

```
Create table Order(
order_number INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
product_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
address_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
user_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
quantity INT(3) NOT NULL,
size VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
status VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
order_date DATE NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (order_number),
FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
REFERENCES User (user_id),
FOREIGN KEY (product_id)
REFERENCES Product (product_id),
FOREIGN KEY (address_id)
REFERENCES Address (address_id)
)ENGINE = INNODB
```

The specific error I get is:

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Order(
```

order_number INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
product_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
address_' at line 1

Comment: `ORDER` which is the name of your table you specified is a reserved keyword. Here is a full list of reserved keywords: [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just use `order` like that as it's a keyword as well; put in in quotes:

```
Create table `Order`(
order_number INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
product_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
address_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
user_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
quantity INT(3) NOT NULL,
size VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
status VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
order_date DATE NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (order_number),
FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
REFERENCES User (user_id),
FOREIGN KEY (product_id)
REFERENCES Product (product_id),
FOREIGN KEY (address_id)
REFERENCES Address (address_id)
)ENGINE = INNODB
```

Comment: that's so simple and stupid, thank you.  I'm probably going to change its name just to prevent me from having to use quotes all over the place.

Comment: that wouldn't be a bad idea; though 'using quotes all over' is in itself not a bad idea either.

Comment: tick marks make me crazy when coding MYSQL